# Automated Azure SQL DB export fails

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup, azure-sql-database

Like the posting I reference below, we have also experienced failure in our automated Azure SQL DB backup. The automated backup has been running for months, but failed this weekend. In our case, this is for a Database running V2. Note that while the entry for AutoExportToStorageAccount succeeded, there is no .bacpac file to be found.

Has anybody else seen this?

[Automated Azure SQL DB export fails - indexing for document type .xml is not supported on MS Azure SQL DB v12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919344/automated-azure-sql-db-export-fails-indexing-for-document-type-xml-is-not-sup)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919344/automated-azure-sql-db-export-fails-indexing-for-document-type-xml-is-not-sup

Comment: Satyanarayana, what makes you think it's a duplicate? #1 we are not running V12. #2 we do not have an XML indexes. #3 the indexes are the same ones that have been exporting fine for months.

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into the older portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) and running the backup/export manually there.

We had an automated backup that started failing that we were able to resolve the issue by running the export manually from the older portal and viewing the very detailed error message from the notifications tab on the bottom of the portal. You can read more details about the exact issue here: [Automated azure sql export fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857125/automated-azure-sql-export-fails/32415939#32415939)